# Randomly sample a dataframe until all individuals are detected

Tags: r

An example of my data is as follows (though I have hundreds of rows). Each ID is unique, and there may be multiple individuals associated with one ID (for example, individuals A and D).

```
ID individual
1  A
2  B
3  A
4  C
5  D
6  D
7  D
```

I would like to randomly select an ID 1000 times with the opportunity to re-sample the same ID, and store how many unique individuals are accumulated over this sampling scheme.

I would then like to generate a plot that shows how many ID's would need to be selected to accumulate all of the unique individuals, so that the curve reaches asymptote with ID's on the x-axis and individuals on the y-axis.

**EDIT:**
My description of the desired plot above is unclear. The edit is as follows:

I would like to generate a plot that shows the **number of times** an ID has to get selected (with replacements) for all the unique individuals to accumulate.. NOT the number of unique IDs associated with unique individuals. The curve should then reach asymptote with x number of times IDs were selected once all of the unique individuals accumulate.

For example, if there were 500 ID's associated with 200 individuals, I would like to sample the pool of 500 ID's 1000 times (or however many times), while putting IDs back in the pool after each sample, to see how many times we would have to sample that pool in order for all 200 individuals to accumulate.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to randomly select an ID 1000 times with the opportunity
> to re-sample the same ID, and store how many unique individuals are
> accumulated over this sampling scheme.

You can use `slice_sample` from `dplyr` to sample rows from a data frame. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

N_id <- 2000
N_individuals <- 50

df_full <- data.frame(id = 1:N_id,
                      individual = sample(1:N_individuals, N_id, replace = TRUE))

df_sample <- slice_sample(df_full, n = 1000, replace = TRUE)

unique_individuals <- length(unique(df_sample$individual))
```

> I would then like to generate a plot that shows how many ID's would
> need to be selected to accumulate all of the unique individuals, so
> that the curve reaches asymptote with ID's on the x-axis and
> individuals on the y-axis.

You can wrap that into a function to produce values for different numbers of ids and individuals (and draws for that matter), and then plot the different values using `ggplot` or another plotting tool. However, this strikes me as a combinatorics question perhaps better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/, since these values will fully depend on the number of ids, individuals.

Edit: in a function:

```
N_id <- 2000
N_individuals <- 50
N_draws <- 1000

sample_df_parameterized <- function(n_id, n_individuals, n_draws) {
  
  df_full <- data.frame(id = 1:n_id,
                        individual = sample(1:n_individuals, n_id, replace = TRUE))
  
  df_sample <- slice_sample(df_full, n = n_draws, replace = TRUE)
  
  unique_individuals <- length(unique(df_sample$individual))
  
  result_df <- data.frame(n_id = n_id,
                          n_individuals = n_individuals,
                          n_draws = n_draws,
                          unique_individuals = unique_individuals)
  
  return(result_df)
  
}

sample_df_parameterized(n_id = N_id,
                        n_individuals = N_individuals,
                        n_draws = N_draws)
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response, @Julian. Is it possible to please direct how to wrap this into a function? I am familiar with how to use ggplot, however less so on the steps required prior to plotting.

Comment: Sure, I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt in base R, with a custom function to do the counting of cumulative unique values:

Larger example data:

```
set.seed(2)
dat <- data.frame(ID=1:250, individual=sample(1:100, 500, replace=TRUE))
length(unique(dat$individual))
##100
```

Sample, count cumulative values, and plot:

```
tmp <- dat[sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)), 1000, replace=TRUE),]

cumfun <- function(x) lengths(Reduce(union, x, accumulate=TRUE))
idcum <- cumfun(tmp$ID)
indcum <- cumfun(tmp$individual)

plot(idcum, indcum, type="l")
```

You could also spruce the plot up a bit if you like to add a line of best fit of your choosing, and some nicer axes:

```
plot(idcum, indcum, type="l", ylim=c(0,100), las=1,
     xlab="Cumulative ID count", ylab="Cumulative Individuals count",
     cex.lab=0.8, cex.axis=0.8, lty=2)
f <- function(x,a,b) {x/(a+b*x)}
fit <- nls(indcum ~ f(idcum,a,b), start=c(a=1,b=1))
curve(do.call(f, c(list(x), coef(fit))), add=TRUE, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail! This is what I am looking for. How would the code be modified so that ID's continue getting sampled after individuals have all been accumulated, so that the curve essentially flattens out (i.e., once all 100 individuals have been accumulated, keep sampling, so that the dashed line flattens out as more ID's get sampled (because there are no more individuals to be selected). Thanks again.

Comment: I have since discovered that my description of the desired plot was not totally clear in my original post. I have now edited the desired plot.